# How to Blend/Blur Two Images in OpenglES/OpenGl , So that output looks like a windows aero theme

Tags: windows, opengl-es, themes, aero

I am in process of implementing this Windows aero theme on my Arm Mali GPU
Follow this image, i want a effect like this
checkout this  http://vistastyles.org/wp-content/uploads/2007/06/windows_aero_by_blingboy31.jpg

my question is how do  identify which area of image(top) is intermixed with image(bottom)
it may possible that there may be multiple images getting overlapped, So do i need to take weight of each image or layer to identify the amount of blur to show.. ??

& how do i draw the images ? do i need to draw the blur image of background first & then normal image or other way??

Any help is appericiated...

**SEASON 2**
/*****************************************************************************/
Well I tried the datenWolf's way, But stucked at blur shader

I used this fragment shader for blurring but it doesn't give the exact Translucent effect, I wish to get

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D sceneTex;

uniform float rt_w;
uniform float rt_h;
uniform float vx_offset;

float offset[3] = float[]( 0.0, 1.3846153846, 3.2307692308 );
float weight[3] = float[]( 0.2270270270, 0.3162162162, 0.0702702703 );

void main() 
{ 
  vec3 tc = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  if (gl_TexCoord[0].x<(vx_offset-0.01))
  {
    vec2 uv = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
    tc = texture2D(sceneTex, uv).rgb * weight[0];
    for (int i=1; i<3; i++) 
    {
      tc += texture2D(sceneTex, uv + vec2(offset[i])/rt_w, 0.0).rgb * weight[i];
      tc += texture2D(sceneTex, uv - vec2(offset[i])/rt_w, 0.0).rgb * weight[i];
    }
  }
  else if (gl_TexCoord[0].x>=(vx_offset+0.01))
  {
    tc = texture2D(sceneTex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).rgb;
  }
  gl_FragColor = vec4(tc, 1.0);
}
```

I was looking for a Blur effect as shown in this link
http://incubator.quasimondo.com/processing/superfast_blur.php

but this software algorithm is not working in my code, Any help for a Blur Shader With this kind of effect will be helpful, I am using OpenGLES 2.0 on Arm mali

Answer (score 2):

There's no detection process involved in window composition. Every window is available as a separate texture and the windows are drawn in depth order using a blurring step inbetween.

It is done about this. You have two framebuffer objects **A** and **B** for the whole screen. *Foreach* window you

1. draw the area the window covers from **B** to **A** with a blurring filter applied
2. you draw the actual window contents on top of this to **B**
3. swap A←→B

repeat for every window in depth order. Basically this comes out as a number of texture switches, and although those are sort of expensive, the number of (overlapping) windows on a screen will always be within reasonable figures, so this is not really a problem.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf, since i am a very basic user to opengl I may sound silly with these questions please bare, 1) How do i identify the area the window covers from B to A ?  2) i think this solution includes two passes , is it possible to do it one pass ??

Comment: @GeekPanther: You're given a list of records of each containing the window position and extents. You do not try to "identify" the window area using some image processing. The exact structure of this record is defined by the windowing system you use – or either implement yourself.

Comment: need help with blur shader, Follow Question, Edited (SEASON 2)